# UICollectionView inside UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

So I'm trying to create a collection view inside a tableview following this:
https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

All is going well until a problem occurs here.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, 
forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

guard let tableViewCell = cell as? TableViewCell else { return }

tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
}
```

I receive the error 'Cannot invoke 'setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate' with and argument of list type '(ViewController, forRow: Int)''

What's the problem here?

Comment: Not really an answer but I would let tableview cell to be delegate for collection and implement what is needed there.

Comment: Have you adopted the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocols, as per the subsequent paragraph in the tutorial ("OK awesome! But now we have a problem....")?